# Google Chrome Extension, closing Persistent background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which has a persistent background page in order to stream audio even when the user closes chrome. What I would like is to implement an option for the user to disable audio streaming after chrome has been closed. Right now I am detecting when all chrome windows have been closed and pausing audio, however chrome remains 'open' in the task manager and system tray (note that running in background chrome setting is enabled). This stops audio playback but the chrome process remains open in task manger and the icon remains in the system tray. By contrast if I completely disable the extension and then close chrome, the application closes completely and no system tray icon remains.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993115/chrome-extension-close-background-page-after-closing-chrome) suggests that only a user can explicitly close chrome if there is a persistent background page, My goal isn't to close chrome explicitly but simply prevent ***MY*** extension from being the one keeping chrome open (depending on user specified options), therefore an event page doesn't seem to be a good fit.

Is there a function call or some other programmatic way I can close my persistent background page once all windows have been closed, if that option has been enabled? Or am I stuck with the chrome application staying open because the background page is persistent?

Comment: Try [Persistent background page on demand or an event page that doesn't unload?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58577052)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer to my own question so I'll post it here. In order to have a background page you do not need the "Background" permission declared in your manifest. This permission is what allows the extension to stay open after chrome has closed (and potentially open before chrome?) rather than being necessary to have a background page. So a persistent background page will close with chrome if this permission is not set, and will stay open even after chrome is closed if it is set.

Bearing this in mind, the solution for me was to set the "background" permission to optional, and enable it if I wanted my extension to stay open after close, then remove the permission if I didn't want it staying open after close (the user now has an option to toggle this).